# How to use "Cloud Functions for Firebase" trace id you see in the logs?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, trace, stackdriver

Cloud functions for firebase's logs contain a `trace` id.

See example [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gw0AC.png)

Do anyone knows how to use this ?

As far as I can tell, the [StackDriver Trace](https://cloud.google.com/trace/docs/overview) documentation makes no mention of Firebase or cloud functions.

Answer (score 0):

[Firebase documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/writing-and-viewing-logs) has detailed information about logging.
You could use [Stackdriver logger](https://github.com/googleapis/nodejs-logging) for your Cloud Functions project as described [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/writing-and-viewing-logs#custom_stackdriver_logs) instead of `console.log`